# Slack API - scope permissions

Tags: laravel, slack-api

I'm trying to get further user details from the Slack's API.

Currently I'm authenticating users via Slack's OAuth2 that returns a code. I'm currently asking for `scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar`. When I try to ask for more, like `users.profile:read`, the link redirects me to a crash page.

My link for signing in to my app via Slack is like this, for now:

```
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=104847663141.146678941328&scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar"></a>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with Slack works as a kind of sidebar form of OAuth 2.0 authorization for Slack. It's meant to be used for identity, exclusively. So whenever going through the flow and asking for an `identity.*` scope, you'll be restricted from combining it with others.

You can still ask for `users.profile:read`, but you have to do so in a separate authorization attempt where it's not among the momentarily requested scopes. It'll then be added to the user token you already hold for that user.